# How to parse JSON object and get its value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to get the value of an array but I can't get it, this is the array:

```
[{0: {value: 2, label: "ARKANSAS"}}]


Try to use JSON.parse (object) and I generate the following error VM20617: 1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token or in JSON at position 1
```

and then try to use this:

```
JSON.stringify (selectedOption)
```

and it returns this value to me:

```
 [{0: {value : 2, label: "ARKANSAS"}}]
```

Comment: If you would like to check if your JSON string is valid or not, you can try parsing the JSON string using an online JSON parser like https://convertonline.org/json/parser/. This would come in handy to check if your JSON string is a valid one, and then proceed with the next steps like using JSON.parse() function.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is wrong thats why you can't parse it.

***Its supposed to look like this:***

```
[
   {
      "0":{
         "value":2,
         "label":"ARKANSAS"
      }
   }
]
```

A JSON key cannot be an integer it can only be a string but its value is able to be an integer.

Example

```js
var json = JSON.parse('{ "test":{ "value":2, "label":"ARKANSAS" } }');
document.write(json.test.label);
```

In this example I replaced the ***"0"*** with something else otherwise It wont work. Also since this is an object and not an array you need to remove these "[]"
and turn it into this:

***{ "test":{ "value":2, "label":"ARKANSAS" } }***

Don't make an integer the name of a key.

Comment: Also you were missing curly brackets you never closed the object within the array.

Comment: I forgot to say sorry

Comment: I updated the answer it should show you how to parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is a representation of JS object in string. Via `JSON.stringify` you can convert JS object or array to JSON and via `JSON.parse` you can convert back to JS object or array. So in your case your initial value is a JS array and you can try it to convert from JSON to JS but it doesn't sense.
You can use your array just as a common JS array.

Comment: I get the value like this {"value": 9, "label": "NORTH CAROLINA"} how to access value 9 in foreach

Answer (score 0):

You pass the object inside array, just access it as an array, stringify then parse into js object,

```js
selectedOption = [{0: {value: 2, label: "ARKANSAS"}}] // i guest this is your variable

var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectedOption[0]));

// to access
console.log(obj[0].value)
console.log(obj[0].label)
```